# React jest testing. Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined with google js api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, testing, jestjs

Hi guys I've setup the Google Maps JavaScript API and its working all fine, but my tests all fail now with the error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined.

Here is what my component looks like

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import List from './List'
    import { fetchPlaces } from '../../store/actions/places'
    const google = window.google
    export class Places extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

    const pyrmont = { lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196 };

    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('map'))
    // this.props.fetchPlaces('fitzroy')
    const request = {
        location: pyrmont,
        radius: 500, type:
            ['restaurant'],
        placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
        fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry']
    };

    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


    function callback(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            console.log(place)
        }
    }

   }
....rest of component
```

Here's what my test looks like

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { render, renderIntoDocument } from 'react-testing-library'
    import 'jest-dom/extend-expect'
    import { Places } from '../../Places/Places'

   const baseProps = {
    fetchPlaces: jest.fn(),
   };

    test('it shows a loading message when places are being loaded on mount', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Places loading={true} places={[]} {...baseProps} />)
    expect(container).toHaveTextContent('Loading')
    });
```

First line of the error stack is
"at Places.componentDidMount (src/components/Places/Places.js:13:34)"

EDIT: I've setup a mock of the google api in my test file and if I console.log the google object its no longer undefined but I still get the same error in my test.

```
const setupGoogleMock = () => {

const google = {
    maps: {
        places: {
            AutocompleteService: () => { },
            PlacesServiceStatus: {
                INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
                NOT_FOUND: 'NOT_FOUND',
                OK: 'OK',
                OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
                REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
                UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
                ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
            },
        },
        Geocoder: () => { },
        GeocoderStatus: {
            ERROR: 'ERROR',
            INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
            OK: 'OK',
            OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
            REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
            UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
            ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
        },
    },
};
      global.window.google = google;
    };

    beforeAll(() => {
        setupGoogleMock();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran ran into a similar issue today, with an error of: `TypeError: window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService is not a constructor`

I found a fix from CRA issue #955 - [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/955)

Basically you change the AutoCompleteService line to `Autocomplete: class {}`. Keep the rest of that mock file the same.

Although, the test that I have (which is now passing) is just the basic CRA initial test of 'it renders without crashing' but it should work out for you as well

Answer (score 0):

Some modules might not work well inside a testing environment, or may not be as essential to the test itself. Mocking out these modules with dummy replacements can make it easier to write tests for your own code. [Click Here For Detail](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#mocking-modules)

```
import MockedMap from "./map";

jest.mock("./map", () => {
  return function DummyMap(props) {
    return (
      <div data-testid="map">
        {props.center.lat}:{props.center.long}
      </div>
    );
  };
});
```